# Can a drummer hit the snare, ride, and crash at the same time?

Tags: drums

I'm producing a song and I'm using virtual drums via midi notes to achieve the drum sounds. I want a real drummer to eventually perform this piece so I'm asking you drummers out there if it's practically possible for a drummer to hit the snare, ride, and crash at the same time (this is performed inside a sequence of other "hits" (if that makes any sense), so it isn't a thing performed *independently* in the piece)..

It doesn't seem possible from an outsider's perspective or if it is possible it doesn't seem to be an easy thing to accomplish (and it may be a problem if it's a too advanced thing to do)..

PS: I've probably gave you insufficient data about my situation (due to a lack of real drumming knowledge) so feel free to ask for more info and I'll *try* to answer..

Comment: Given that most drummers have only two arms (there are those with fewer), and snare, crash and ride all need to be sticked...

Comment: Are you imagining one stick hitting both the crash and the ride? There exist crash+ride cymbals that combine the ~~worst~~ best of both worlds.

Comment: I'm with @JohnnyApplesauce on this one… but the only kits that come with crash/rides also cost less than 50 bucks… or pence… & were probably produced in the 60s :P

Comment: IMO, nothing essential will be lost from your arrangement palette if you restrict to only one cymbal hit at a time. Either ride, crash/splash/china or hi-hat. But only one. There are some special cases like pedalling high-hats, but they aren't essential for most things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I spent the entire 90s being paid (quite handsomely, tyvm ;) to seek & destroy ***3-handed-drummer syndrome*** in midi/sample playback songs & styles for a major instrument manufacturer.

**No**, a drummer cannot do that & someone, somewhere, will spot if you do it.

On the other hand [pun intended] any half-decent drummer can be riding the ride, flip in a quick crash & be back to the ride before anyone would even notice he'd missed one. The crash will easily cover a fair bit of where the ride would have been, so you don't need it there at the same time.

Unless you are producing 'pure electronic'/sample playback music, where frankly anything goes, then avoid 3-handedness like the plague.
It really does help, when programming drums to actually know how a drummer would do it - even if that drummer is better than you;) Study drummers, they will teach you things about drum programming. You don't have to be able to play yourself… so long as *someone can*.

Comment: Sorry, cannot resist, " (quite handsomely, tyvm ;) " looks mismatch: https://xkcd.com/541/   ;)

Comment: Anything wrong with using a 'crash' stroke on the ride for that one hit? Works for me...

Comment: @Tim - rides just don't crash properly - they also end up swinging around making a mess of your natty little be-bop swing - ka-ting-ga-ding-a-ding-ga-ding Personally, I use paper-thin crashes, but my ride is like a train wheel.